# Every Time I try to make a game and try to code this Error pop up

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

**So Every Time I try to make a game in Unity this error pop up** :

> *Win32Exception: ApplicationName='E:\Unity Edtor\2020.3.37f1\Editor\Data\Tools\RoslynScripts\unity_csc.bat', CommandLine='/noconfig @Temp/UnityTempFile-54dc7559203bbb3499c8dea19348dd7e', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) (at <39d8670c8f6e487fb992d3c14d754584>:0)
> System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () (at <39d8670c8f6e487fb992d3c14d754584>:0)
> (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
> UnityEditor.Utils.Program.Start (System.EventHandler exitCallback) (at :0)
> UnityEditor.Utils.Program.Start () (at :0)
> UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.MicrosoftCSharpCompiler.BeginCompiling () (at :0)
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.CompilationTask.QueuePendingAssemblies () (at :0)
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.CompilationTask.Poll () (at :0)
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation.CompileScriptAssemblies (UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.ScriptAssembly[] scriptAssemblies, UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.ScriptAssemblySettings scriptAssemblySettings, System.String tempBuildDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.CompilationTaskOptions compilationTaskOptions, UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation+CompileScriptAssembliesOptions compileScriptAssembliesOptions) (at :0)
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation.CompileScriptsWithSettings (UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.ScriptAssemblySettings scriptAssemblySettings, System.String tempBuildDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.TargetAssembly[]& notCompiledTargetAssemblies, System.String[]& notCompiledScripts, UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.CompilationTaskOptions compilationTaskOptions) (at :0)
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation.CompileScripts (UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorScriptCompilationOptions editorScriptCompilationOptions, UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup platformGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget platform, System.String[] extraScriptingDefines, UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.CompilationTaskOptions compilationTaskOptions) (at :0)
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation.TickCompilationPipeline (UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorScriptCompilationOptions options, UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup platformGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget platform, System.String[] extraScriptingDefines) (at :0)
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilationInterface.TickCompilationPipeline (UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorScriptCompilationOptions options, UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup platformGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget platform, System.String[] extraScriptingDefines) (at :0)
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilationInterface:TickCompilationPipeline(EditorScriptCompilationOptions, BuildTargetGroup, BuildTarget, String[])*

If any one know how to fix it please help me.

I tried to solve it through youtube videos but can't rid of this error.

Comment: It looks like your windows is unable to run cmd for some reason It's unrelated to unity it self .

Comment: Theres a thread on the Unity forums about this

Comment: Yes  , but idk maybe its a problem in the tool because it happened with others as well from what i've read ,

Comment: and they all had good reasons.. do you fit any of those reasons?